# Google Game Services OAuth key for production

Tags: android, oauth, google-play-games

I've added Google game services inside application (Leaderboard, achievements). Everything works fine in debug.. on my machine.........

OAuth Client Id (for debug) in https://cloud.google.com/console looks like 6666666.apps.googleusercontent.com

I try to generate new OAuth Client (for production, with release key)... and .... google generates an Client with a name like '6666666-somenoise.apps.googleusercontent.com' ... and this doesn't work! It always says "Application missconfiguration" .. but everything is correct APP_ID, SHA1 & package name.

Google game services troubleshooting documentation is useless.

I made a test application again.. and it works (Client ID is generated like in example above.. without that noise)...

So. of course I can remove my current project.. and create again..with release key config by default.. but that's not a way! We have 100 achievements added in that project.. with all translations (in many languages).... and google of course doesn't allow to Export/Import them :(

Comment: according to the documentation ... "Warning: Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google Developers Console. If you do so, Play Games services will not associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause errors during gameplay." .... THAT OPTION IS ACCESSIBLE ONLY ONCE. What should I do for an existing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was fixed by an unknown miracle.

How to fix:

1. Remove any Client ID created in cloud.gogle.com.
2. Remove Linked Apps from your game in 'game services'.
   (play.google.com/apps/publish)
3. go to smoke ... 2-3 hours.. maybe more... let google remove that IDs
   (I guess they mark them as deleted.. and if you try to create a new
   one.. they'll reuse the delete keys)
4. Go to game services Linked Apps (play.google.com/apps/publish)
5. Add a new Linked app for ex 'My Game Debug' ... then press
   "Authorize" ... the key created here will work
6. Add a new Linked app for ex 'My Game Release' ... then press
   "Authorize" .. the key created here will work.

Answer (score 1):

## More about changing client ID for Google+ authentication

Just for future reference, on https://console.developers.google.com you can manage the client IDs. See selected menu option in screenshot below (*the actual values are not in picture but you should be able to find it this way*).

[image]

## Google Play Game Services

If you follow the steps from https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling to link an app to your game play services this is part of the game play services flow. See **Step 3. Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID**

However if you link the game again with the same package this wizard is skipped so there is no way to change the SHA1 value from the play game console.